# Implementation of semi parametric methods

Tags: r, matlab, binary-data, semiparametric

Has anyone worked with semi parametric methods to estimate parameters with binary outcome? Examples are like Cosslett (1983) or Ichimura or Klein-Spady. In other words we are looking for semi parametric methods instead of probit/logit.

I was wondering if anyone has written R code or Matlab code in this regard that he/she could share?

Comment: This is better in several ways than the previous version, though I'm curious why you didn't just edit the previous one. Nevertheless some of the problems I listed there remain.

Comment: I didn't know how to edit the previous post. I googled already before coming here but found no code for the all the above methods. Also I am going to leave my question as is for now. Anyone who has worked with semi parametric methods for binary outcome would understand it. If not will post a specific implementation question again.

Comment: To edit, you click the "edit" link at the bottom of the post (you can always edit your own posts if you registered and you're logged in - you don't need the edit privilege). I certainly wasn't asking you to never post a question about implementation (some implementation questions are certainly on topic, because they often have a statistical dimension), but to try to keep posts on topic and within the guidelines.